# Cython with pythonxy

Tags: cython, pythonxy

I'm trying to use Cython but I can't seem to find a way of getting it to work.

1. I installed pythonxy, which comes with Cython.
2. I installed MS VS 2008 Express (https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=7729279)
3. Then I installed the Cython plugin for pythonxy from the standard plugins web page (https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/StandardPlugins) just in case.

However, I get this error:

```
ImportError: Building module MyCyModule failed: ["ValueError: [u'path']\n"]
```

I have my MWE below:

---

MyCyModule.pyx

```
print 'Hello World'
```

---

TestCyModule.py

```
import pyximport
pyximport.install()
import MyCyModule
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this I installed: **Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5**

Full credit to this blog post: http://springflex.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-fix-valueerror-when-trying-to.html, although I didn't need the extra steps copying the bat files (point 3 and onward)

Download from here (I used the Web Setup from the installation instructions and unchecked the documentation which saved a lot of space):
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en